# Complex grid patters for chair

Tags: modeling

I need some help in creating a complex(might not be complex) grid pattern for the back support of a chair.

I attached the image it is based on.

Please note that I have also created the outer frame, do let me know if that's necessary or if I'm headed in the right direction. [image: Side view]

[image: Front view]

[image: Frame I created]

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple and basic way I would go about it.
Made you this short video.
-Subdivide a Plane, Shape with "Proportional editing", Add wireframe mod and Subdivision surface -
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/wvr-vZ1kEcA)